# How is the block size of Bitcoin 1MB whereas the algorithm it uses (SHA-256) has a block size of only 512 bits?

Tags: blockchain, sha256, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I have just started learning about Blockchain and I am still new to most of the concepts. So please help me out with this. I have read in my class notes that SHA-256 algorithm has a block size of 512 bits, and Bitcoin uses this algorithm too. But when I researched online it says that Bitcoin has a block size of 1MB.

What am I missing over here?

Comment: All hash algorithms like SHA have a defined way of handling larger input, one block at a time.  They’d be useless for most practical purposes, otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the concept of "Block" is different in the context of a hash function and the Bitcoin blockchain.

In the context of hash functions, SHA256 processes input data in chunks, and the size limit of each data chunk is called block size. In the case of SHA256, the block/data chunk size limit is 512bits.

In the context of Bitcoin, there's a data structure called "block". Each block contains metadata info and a group of transactions. The hash of block i is packed into the metadata of block i+1, which constructs a connection between these 2 blocks, thus it's called Blockchain. It's like a chain of blocks with each block containing the hash of its previous block. The size limit of each block, in the context of Bitcoin, is 1MB. It limits how many transactions can be packed into a single block because the size of the block matters for the decentralization of the blockchain. Lower the size of the block, lower the requirement for the network nodes' bandwidth and thus more nodes can join the network.

If you want to learn more comprehensively about Bitcoin, this is the go to material I would recommend: https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook